# Exporting a hi-res image from a UIView that contains other views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiview

I am trying to export an image from a UIView that contains a UIImage view and some labels. I am not sure I am going about this the right way.  I want to export everything in the view and maintain the layout. I want to export at 1536 x 2048.

I am using the following code with renderInContext to grab an image of the main view (UIView). Kind of works, but the layout gets messed up, basically the layout changes and the labels do not scale properly. Is renderInContext the right way to go for something like this? Is there a better way?

[image: output]

you can download the whole project here: http://tinyurl.com/7qvhqtp

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(1536, 2048));
viewOutput.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1536, 2048);
[[viewOutput layer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image,nil,nil,nil);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you did to get a bigger image was to change the frame but the labels did not have the correct autoresize masks nor did their font size change. You can clearly see this in the "after running code" image that the label did neither move nor change size.

First, If you wan the label to change its frame when the superview's frame changes (are the labels subviews of the image? If not you may need to calculate their new frames yourself) then you should give it a suitable auroresizing mask. In your case you would want it to have a fixed distance to the bottom of the screen and a flexible distance to the top. You would also want the distances to the left and right to be fixed so that the width can be flexible.

This only leaves you with the font size problem. You should calculate the scale factor (how many times bigger everything gets) and multiply the current font size with that scale factor.

Answer (score 2):

This is the code I use to save the current UIView as an image. The layout gets saved perfectly.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, self.view.opaque, 0.0);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

I'm not 100% sure, but there might be some issues with `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` vs `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`.

On the other hand the problem might be in your view's subview's autoresizing mask if your view has the `autoresizesSubviews` set to YES. I'd try to disable it if you do not have the support for rotations or at least before changing your view's frame.

Comment: The only different between the `...withOptions` and the other is that you can specify if the image should be opaque and a scale factor to the image